# excel substitute multiple instances in different character positions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a dataset from a sql database with around 6500 rows with one column with fields containing multiple values.

Example

```
Cell A1 3.00GGG1.00DDD2.00EEE1.00DEF5.00TTT             
Cell A2 10.00ABC1.00DDD2.00EEE1.00DEF
```

.00 is the only consistent series of characters in the string
I need to introduce a "," to be able to use the text to columns tool to split the values into different columns thereafter
A complication is the number to the left of the decimal can vary and can be 10 or larger so the position of the comma could be 1 or 2 positions to the left of the decimal

So I need to a achieve

```
Cell A1 ,3.00GGG,1.00DDD,2.00EEE,1.00DEF,5.00TTT                
Cell A2 ,10.00ABC,1.00DDD,2.00EEE,1.00DEF
```

To ultimately achieve through using text to column

```
3.00GGG 1.00DDD 2.00EEE 1.00DEF 5.00TTT 
10.00ABC    1.00DDD 2.00EEE 1.00DEF
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to achieve this through a formula or macro?

thanks!

Comment: Are the GGG etc. letters, or some other non-numeric character?

Comment: Hi they are letters thanks

Answer (score 1):

I never thought I'd say that, but for me it actually works using Word.

Copy over your rows to a Word document. Open Find/Replace `(CTRL + H)`, click on `More>>` to open the advanced menu and tick the box `Use wildcards`.

Then type into Find What `([0-9]{1,2}.)` and into Replace with `,\1`. Click on Replace all and copy everything back into an excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something for you using RegEx. It does have a loophole, try this and if it does not work, we will work on the loophole.

```
call findMatch("3.00GGG1.00DDD2.00EEE1.00DEF5.00TTT ","[A-Za-z]\d")

Function findMatch(strValue, strPattern)
    Dim objRegEx
    Dim objPosition
    Dim strPosition

    strNewVal = strValue
'find out how many different strings will be there
    countOfStrings = len(strNewVal) - len(replace(strNewVal, ".", ""))

    strCompiledString = ""
'Create regular expression
        Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        objRegEx.Pattern = strPattern

'loop to break the string up and tie it with comma
    for i= 1 to countOfStrings
        if not objRegEx.Test(strValue) then
'if condition to check whether or not there are any matches
            strCompiledString = strCompiledString & "," & strValue
                exit for
        end if
        Set objPosition = objRegEx.Execute(strValue)
        strPosition = objPosition(0).FirstIndex
        findMatch= strPosition

'based on match index, add the left part of the string to the variable strCompiledString
    if(strCompiledString="") then
        strCompiledString = mid(strValue,1,strPosition+1)
    else
            strCompiledString = strCompiledString & "," & mid(strValue,1,strPosition+1)
    end if

'remove the already processed substring from the main string
    strValue = mid(strValue,strPosition+2)

next

'now we have it
msgbox("BOOOOM : " & strCompiledString)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified a UDF I wrote for getting the nth number from a string to get the nth number plus letters:-

```
Function GetNthNumber(s As String, n As Integer) As String

Dim c, testNumber, number As String

s = s & "0"

Dim i, j, count As Integer   
Dim inNumber As Boolean

inNumber = False

' Loop through each character of string

For i = 1 To Len(s)    
c = Mid(s, i, 1)

' Part of a number - append new character or finish number

    If inNumber Then   
        If Not (IsNumeric(number & c)) Then
            inNumber = False  
        End If
            number = number & c
    Else

' Not part of a number - start new number or do nothing

        If IsNumeric(c) Then    
            If count = n Or i = Len(s) Then Exit For
            inNumber = True
            number = c
            count = count + 1              
        Else    
            number = number + c
        End If                       
    End If
Next i

'Return nth number or #Value error

If count >= n Then
    GetNthNumber = number
Else
    GetNthNumber = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End If
End Function
```

To use it, call the function to get the first number, and pull it across until it errors out

```
=IFERROR(GetNthNumber($A1,COLUMN(A:A)),"")
```

[image]